# How to get Sonar to report both Java and JavaScript tests run by Maven

Tags: maven, junit, sonarqube, jasmine-maven-plugin

Our project uses Maven as the build tool and we are using Sonar to track quality. JUnit tests are executed by SureFire and the results are displayed in Sonar. We've added some JavaScript tests which are run by the [jasmine-maven-plugin](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin) and want to include these results in the Sonar project.

The plugin generates a JUnit style XML report. How should we go about including the XML report in Sonar? Do we want to merge the XML reports as part of the build maybe?

Comment: From my own experience running Sonar twice was required (and that was just to have violations, without jasmine-maven-plugin). However I'll have to dig somewhat to find out exact specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure the format generated by Jasmine is compliant with the JUnit XML format expected by the JavaScript Plugin : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Unit+Tests+Execution+Reports+Import

You can also have a look at the format supported by the Generic Test Coverage Plugin : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Coverage

You don't need to merge the XML reports, there are different sonar.* properties to feed depending on the way you want to load your data: thru the JavaScript Plugin or the Generic Test Coverage. As a consequence, you don't need to run SonarQube analysis twice.